# Are question about versioning of software on topic?

Tags: discussion

[This question about Swift versions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/375347/what-versions-of-swift-are-supported-by-what-versions-of-xcode) (now deleted) was closed as "too broad". But I think it is very specific. As a counter argument, [here is a question about versioning of C# self-answered by Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c) with 2000+ upvotes on both question and answer and it is [continuously being updated](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/247623/revisions#spacer-6c2e0582-a73d-4d36-aee8-034131c22d09) as new versions are coming out. As a C# developer myself I find this Jon's post very useful and educational. The [linked meta post answer in first comment](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7537/why-do-some-examples-and-list-of-things-questions-get-closed/7538#7538) suggests to ask questions on Quora or Reddit. Pardon me, but I disagree. This is clearly programming (or software development) related question and SO/SE is a perfect place to ask such questions.

**So, are questions about software versioning on topic here? Should we move it to SO?**

Comment: FWIW, I voted to close the question as "too broad" because nobody had added a custom close message of "This is a question for the Swift support team" and the 3 previous close votes were for "too broad". I was too lazy to go against the stream and come up with my own close reason, but I think the question is clearly not a good fit for this site for the reasons @RobertHarvey mentions in his answer. I apologize for choosing a misleading close reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, questions that are proxies for any company's customer support do not do well, here or on Stack Overflow, for the simple reason that *we are not experts of the subject matter.*

I applaud Jon for that C# versioning question.  Jon clearly saw a problem: people were constantly asking questions about C# versions on Stack Overflow, so he crafted a canonical question/answer pair so that the community could immediately close further questions as duplicates.

If you look hard enough, you can find any question/answer pair on Stack Overflow or Software Engineering that supports your particular viewpoint about site topicality.

Comment: `any question/answer pair ... supports your particular viewpoint about site topicality` to that I would say "any piece of software have versioning as part of its nature; can't ask a question without version of some software being a relevant variable". But regardless, do we keep the question on hold?

Comment: The likelihood that anyone here has inside information about a product version that's not even supposed to exist is vanishingly small.  The version numbers referenced in the question are not even mentioned in the project changelog. 
 The OP should direct their inquiry to the project owners on Github.