# Would "Has <programming practice> ever gone badly wrong" questions be on topic here?

Tags: discussion

I'm wondering if questions about whether a given programming practice has ever been the cause of a large problem, would be on topic here.

Note that when I say "programming practice" I mean a way of using one or more programming languages, not features of programming languages.

So programming practices would include particular [design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) or things like [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) but not things like dynamic typing.

I'm fairly certain that any question starting with "What are the worst ways that..." would be considered off-topic, so I would word questions like these in a definitely answerable way. "Has the Singleton Pattern ever gone badly wrong?" is a yes or no question, (which I already know the answer to.) I'm interested in knowing whether a particular technique has a failure mode and how bad it was if so, not in hearing a bunch of horror stories like [this question that was marked non-constructive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169713/whats-the-toughest-bug-you-ever-found-and-fixed) produced or making fun of obviously bad ideas.

(I asked [this same question on SO's meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384828/would-has-programming-practice-ever-gone-badly-wrong-questions-be-on-topic-h) and was told it was off-topic.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7537/why-do-some-examples-and-list-of-things-questions-get-closed)

Comment: I don't know any programming practice which does not have a "failure mode", so whatever you ask here, the answer would always be "yes". That would not make it a very interesting question/answer pair, don't you think so?

Answer (score 8):

This would be off topic as it's far too broad.

Like Stack Overflow we're after specific, answerable questions, not a wide ranging discussion.

You'd be better off asking this on somewhere like Quora or Reddit.