# Can I ask about changes in Programming Language version changes here?

Tags: discussion

Can I ask about changes in Programming Language version changes here? Is this appropriate for SE?

Context: I wanted to ask if I can ask here what was changed since JDK 1.8 to 1.12, since I was offscreen for some time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7537/why-do-some-examples-and-list-of-things-questions-get-closed)

Comment: @gnat Since there is a strict amount of changed things that aren't going to change in the future I do not consider this a list question like "What can I use for a Java IDE?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd think that such a question would be down voted, if not closed.

Instead of asking, I would think that the best starting point would be to the changelogs. Most major languages and their toolchains have some kind of published changelog or other documentation to help people when upgrading from one version to the next.

I'd also likely suggest Stack Overflow, since you're in the realm of how to use specific developer tools. Developer tools would include compilers, interpreters, runtimes, and similar.