# Reopen request for my question

Tags: feature-request, reopen-request

I am requesting to have [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/401415/what-are-the-benefits-of-multi-file-programming) question reopened. Because of a flag declined comment, I have been told to ask reopen requests on meta.[image] This image serves as proof, even though this question is a different one. I would like the linked question reopened as I have edited it to add more details and specific questions. Please consider reopening my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a compelling reason for reopening, **as long as the question does not get deleted**.

The topic of the question is IMHO fine in general, though very broad, and it could be seen as a  [list-of-things](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7537/why-do-some-examples-and-list-of-things-questions-get-closed) question, since there are several reasons for splitting up a larger program into multiple files (performance, however, is none of them). I think it already got enough excellent answers, but because of its broadness, it attracted a whole lot of different viewpoints (already 10 answers in total). So I think it is pretty unlikely reopening would bring a new, really better answer than the current top-voted ones.

Note though the question is closed, it still can receive up- and downvotes, as well as the answers can. Let me add that I think your last edit did not improve the question. It just enhances the (possibly wrong) impression you did not understand that the reasons for multi-file programming have nothing in common with the platform or performance. The community here does not really like questions which are biased towards a misunderstanding.