# How to get at least a couple of examples of a topic on which "whole books have been written"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, list-questions

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/416068/what-are-the-tried-and-working-software-development-metodologies

Nowadays all the rage is agile, marketed as superior to waterfall. So what else has been widely successful out there - was my question, and the answer was "there are whole books on design methodologies". How do I ask this in a way as to fit SE guidelines?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7537/why-do-some-examples-and-list-of-things-questions-get-closed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions here are best formulated in the context of a particular problem or issue. It's simply not possible to generate a list of methodologies that work. Most organizations have at least one methodology, some have many. If the organization is successful, it's likely that the software development methodology "works". However, it doesn't mean that a methodology will work for you.

What problem are you trying to solve? What research have you done on this problem to see what other people already say? What have you already done to try to solve it? Why don't you think that any of these solutions will help you? If you can address questions such as those in your question, you may have a good question. If you can't, the Q&A format may not be the best place to ask this type of thing.