# What´s wrong to ask about code checks in typescript

Tags: discussion

Following the rules, stackexchange/SoftwareEngineering is about this topics:

If you have a question about...

- Software development methods and practices
- Requirements, architecture, and design
- Quality assurance and testing
- Configuration management, build, release, and deployment

...then you're probably in the right place to ask your question.

So, [asking a question about differences of code checks in Typescript](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/435957/does-typescript-improve-the-code-quality-beside-the-use-of-types) vs checks in the Js JIT-Compiler are not appropriate in this forum? Why?

Answer (score 3):

The question was closed as being too broad ("needs more focus"), not as being off-topic. Literally, the question is a ["list of things" question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7537/why-do-some-examples-and-list-of-things-questions-get-closed), but since that list would probably be very short, maybe containing only one or two major points, I personally tend to disagree with the close voters here (and voted for reopening). However, closing and reopening is a community process. If you can convince 2 more reopen voters, your question might get reopened (or now, as it was deleted, to get undeleted).

To increase the chance for this, I would heavily recommend to improve the question by giving some examples of what you precisely mean by *"hidden errors other than type errors"*. Currently, that part of your question seems to be a little bit blurry to me.

And I don't buy it when you say "[you need to be a typescript expert for doing so](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9331/9113)", that is a really bad excuse. You wrote *"[for] C++ or Delphi, it seems far more errors are found"* - so I am sure you could give us some examples of errors you have in mind.

Answer (score -2):

More than 50% of the questions are currently closed as Software Engineering, so I suppose, the problem is more that people at stackexchange take themselves too serious. It is not the community, that closes questions. This are single persons. Did they not learn, that there are no stupid questions, but only stupid answers?

About the question:

People recommend to use typescript, because this allows type checks. From my experience with compiled languages, the advantage is overestimated. But compilers can find lot´s of other errors.

JS hat a JIT-compiler, that checks for some errors. My questions was very clear: Does the typescript compiler have any advantages compared to a JIT-compiler in respect to code quality (beside the type checks).

If I need to be a typescript specialist to ask more specific, so probably I would not need to ask. .

Comment: It is actually less than 50%, but the order of magnitude is right. And some of the regular close voters "don't take themselves too serious", they take *the site rules* about the questions which belong here pretty serious. Some of them take them so serious I am convinced they have some form of autism, so please don't judge over them without having that in mind. I think their voting is valueable, since this site is flooded with low-quality question every day, but sometimes they also produce some collateral damage - so don't take that personal.

Comment: Stackexchange act´s like a **closed community** of self-proclaimed "specialists". That´s ok, but that is not what people expect when thy read the tour: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackexchange.com/tour). Mybe they sould change the motto a bit: "Don´t ask stupid questions, newbie, you are wasting our time".

Maybe it´s worth reading some comments on this site: [sitejabber](https://www.sitejabber.com/reviews/stackexchange.com)

Comment: There are 177 different SE sites, each one with a different community, so I don't give much on any kind of critics which lumps them all together.