# Was my question too specific and asked for opinionated answers? - Are there any general-purpose languages which don't support C?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

It seems like a pretty specific question where any answer containing a general purpose language that doesn't support C would qualify. Or is it that there is the possibility of more than one correct answer that makes it disqualified for asking on StackExchange?

---

Responses to comments:

@t-sar: I want to know the answer to my question as I am building large projects in C and want to say definitively "by writing in C this library can be called by any maintained general purpose programming-language".

@erik-eidt: JavaScript might not directly, but Node.js, Deno and Bun do. WASM can also be considered as a way to call C code from JavaScript by ways of Emscripten or newer technologies. Bash has [loadables](http://cfajohnson.com/shell/bash/loadables).

---

Link to my question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/444976

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

> Or is it that there is the possibility of more than one correct answer that makes it disqualified for asking on StackExchange?

and that's exactly the reason why the question was closed. You find an explanation in this [older meta post](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7537/why-do-some-examples-and-list-of-things-questions-get-closed) why our community dislikes list-of-things questions. In short, the Q&A format of this site isn't well suited for such questions.

Moreover, your question has some issues which makes it IMHO opinion based: what counts as a "general-purpose" language? What as a non-toy-language? Do you mean languages where an FFI is part of the language specificiation, or are you having specific language *implementations* in mind (maybe with vendor-specific FFI extensions)? What about languages for platforms like old programmable calculators? What about languages like [Postscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript)? Please don't try to answer these remarks of mind, I am just giving some examples why your question is too vague to be sensibly answerable.