# Why is the question asking about similar concepts of low code unfocused?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The question [What are similar concepts of low code/no code? And how are they different? (closed)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/447978/192731) is closed for being unfocused. I understand that it consists several questions, but I think that they complement each other, and help make the answers more useful. In particular:

- *What are other similar concepts to RAD/UI/Agile/low code?*
  This is the main question
- *Which parts they share and which parts they are different?*
  If the first question is answered and nothing else, then it still leaves a hole in really understanding them
- *In what years each term is coined?*
  This one gives a sense on the history, to understand the context where the term is coined. I think each term focuses on an aspect of a more inclusive concept.
- *Are Graphviz, Winforms, Excel, Airtable, WordPress RAD/UI/Agile/low code?*
  Even when you understand the definitions, having some examples still helps

Why do you think they don't support the main question but rather distract us from answer it thoroughly? And if so, which ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with this post is not just that it contains more than one question. It is the main question alone which is problematic - have a look at this older meta question for a full explanation:

[Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7537/why-do-some-examples-and-list-of-things-questions-get-closed)

So in short, it is not that the question you were asking is uninteresting or off-topic, but this way of asking for a (probably long) list of terms has proven itself not to work well with the Q&A format of the SE sites, and our community is pretty adamant against accepting such questions. Moreover, specificially RAD/Low Code, UI and Agile are three different topics, which can be seen as orthogonal to each other.

Unfortunately, the automatically given explanation for the "needs more focus" closage is often too terse to give enough background information for askers who are wondering why their question got closed.

Another point is that your post does not really show much [research effort](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Probably a huge part of your question can be answered by looking into Wikipedia articles like

- [RAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_application_development)
- [UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_interface)
- [Agile Software Development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development)
- [Low Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-code_development_platform)

I found also this older question on the site about the differences between Agile and RAD:

- [Is Agile a variant of RAD?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180590/is-agile-a-variant-of-rad)

Comment: hmm. So if I remove that question and only focus on the terms I know, and add the definitions, would the question be good?

Comment: @Ooker: I recommend you take some time, do some internet research on your own first, read the articles I linked to above, and when that still leaves some gaps, you may ask specificially about these gaps - one question at a time, presenting what you found and why it did not suit your needs.